# Can I emulate Epson Thermal POS printer?

Tags: xamarin, thermal-printer, epson, virtual-printer, epos

I am working on a Xamarin mobile app and I need to develop print functionality for [Epson Tm-T88 Thermal POS Printer](https://www.epson.co.in/For-Work/Printers/POS-Printers/Epson-TM-T88V-Thermal-POS-Receipt-Printer/p/C31CA85203) and similar printers. I am using [ePOS SDK](https://download.epson-biz.com/modules/pos/index.php?page=single_soft&cid=6857&scat=61&pcat=52) for this and trying to write wrapper code for Xamarin since it is native Android SDK.

Since I do not have the POS printer itself and hence I am constantly sending the apks to the person who has it... My question is whether it is possible to emulate the Thermal printer virtually somehow so that I can test and debug it without owning a real POS printer? Maybe something similar to "print to PDF" functionality where I can test it or Is there any service on cloud which provide the printer and the output somehow?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=pos+printer+emulator

Comment: @Jason I tried again with your google search query but could not find anything useful unfortunately

Comment: @KJ It seems like probably nothing emulator like exists yet, though I am not even sure whether emulators are actually possible for even generic POS printer or say any printer in general. "Print to PDF" is the only thing I know...

Comment: If none of those options work for you then you probably either should ask Epson for suggestions or simply use a physical printer to test.

Comment: It's not a mechanism that you can find them just by looking for them, or you can do it on the side of the project. It's a feature many people conceive and dream of, but it would be impossible to achieve more cost-effectiveness than actually preparing equipment for testing. Even if it does implemented, there will be ongoing costs to keep its functionality and performance correct and to build and maintain user support.

Comment: IF the SDK simply is a wrapper around ESC/POS control sequences, you might write your own emulation, that at least writes to a file with text like `"[monospace]$ 3.14 [bold]Pie"` and test it with a sample list.

Answer (score 1):

For people who stumble on this question in the future. I've been writing an emulator. It's in the early stages but it implements most of the commonly used commands and outputs to png or html.

[Thermal Emulator in Rust (Github)](https://github.com/zachzurn/thermal)